# Why does jQuery dialog shrink while fading out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    hide: {effect: "fadeOut", duration: 5000},
    buttons: {
        Save: function() {
            alert("Saved");
            $("#dialog").dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

I'm using Chrome. [Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/ekihob/3).

When I close the dialog, it hides, but also shrinks.

I didn't tell it to shrink! Why does it do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fade` instead of `fadeOut` will solve the issue.

Check this: http://jsbin.com/alafez/4/edit#preview

Comment: Was just about to post this; took some tinkering to figure it out, heh.

Answer (score 2):

Because fadeIn and fadeOut are not valid values for the show and hide options. If you remove `effect: "fadeOut"`, the result will be same. The valid option is `fade`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    hide: {effect: "fade", duration: 5000},
    buttons: {
        Save: function() {
            alert("Saved");
            $("#dialog").dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Just wrapped your answer inside a code block for readability :)